# Wake-on-Lan without control of router

Tags: wake-on-lan

I am in an apt complex where I plug straight into the wall to get my desktop's internet. I'm attempting to turn my desktop on using my laptop.

WOL works if my laptop is on the same internet through the wifi they have here, using the program WakeMeOnLan.

WOL does not work if my laptop is using my phone's tethered 4g internet.

My landlord refuses to forward any ports (I asked for UDP 9).

Do I have any options (like reverse tunneling?)

I saw this post: [WOL over Internet - without Router customization](https://superuser.com/questions/306978/wol-over-internet-without-router-customization) , but since I can do WOL over my own internet I wondered if it was different.

Answer (score 0):

WOL packets will only be transmitted correctly if sender and receiver are on same network/ LAN segment. There are ways to get it working across subnets by using proxy forwarders, howver you are attempting to send a WOL packet across the internet which will not work.